# multiple regex using perl

Tags: regex, perl, undef

Hi this website already helped me a few times fixing my problems in perl.
this is the first time i have to ask a question because i can't find an answer neither on google nor on stack overflow.

What i am trying to do is to get the content between two words. But the patterns they have to match are changing. I am trying to get the product details. Brand, description, name and so on. I tried to do an regex match after another but unfortunately this doesn't work because $1 stays defined. Trying to undef the $1 variable gives me the error message "read only" which is logical. I will post my code below maybe someone has an Idea how to make it work.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;
use IO::File;
use utf8;
my $nfh = IO::File->new('test.html','w');
my $site = 'http://www.test.de/dp/';
my $sku = '1550043196';
my $url = join('',$site,$sku);
my $content = get $url;
my $name = $1 if ($content =~ m{<span id="productTitle" class="a-size-large">(.*?)</span>}gism);
print "$name\n";

# My attempt of undefying 
#undef $1;

my $marke = $1 if ($content =~ m{data-brand="(.*?)"}gism);
print "$marke\n";
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: could you provide a sample input along with expected output?

Comment: Side note, `my ($marke) = $content =~ m{data-brand="(.*?)"}gism;` is better than `my $marke = $1 if ($content =~ m{data-brand="(.*?)"}gism);`

Answer (score 5):

First, never use construction like:

```
my $var = $val if( $some );
```

according to [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Statement-Modifiers):

> **NOTE**: The behaviour of a **my**, **state**, or **our** modified with a statement
>   modifier conditional or loop construct (for example, **my** $x if ... ) is
>   undefined. The value of the **my** variable may be **undef**, any previously
>   assigned value, or possibly anything else. Don't rely on it. Future
>   versions of perl might do something different from the version of Perl
>   you try it out on. Here be dragons.

The `m//` operator, when the `/g` modifier is specified [in list context, it returns a list of the substrings matched by any capturing parentheses in the regular expression.](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) So, as @Сухой27 says in the comment above, you should to use:

```
my ($some) = $str =~ m/...(...).../g;
```

With simple example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $u="undefined";
my $str = q{some="string" another="one"};

#will match
my ($m1) = $str =~ m/some="(.*?)"/g;
print 'm1=', $m1 // $u, '= $1=', $1 // $u, "=\n";

#will NOT match
my ($m2) = $str =~ m/nothere="(.*?)"/g;
print 'm2=', $m2 // $u, '= $1=', $1 // $u, "=\n";

#will match another
my ($m3) = $str =~ m/another="(.*?)"/g;
print 'm3=', $m3 // $u, '= $1=', $1 // $u, "=\n";
```

prints:

```
m1=string= $1=string=
m2=undefined= $1=string=   #the $1 hold previously matched value
m3=one= $1=one=
```

As you can see, the `$1` remains, when matching NOT successful. The [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Capture-groups) says:

> These special variables, like the %+ hash and the numbered match
>   variables (`$1` , `$2` , `$3` , etc.) are dynamically scoped until the end
>   of the enclosing block or until the next successful match, whichever
>   comes first. (See Compound Statements in perlsyn.)
>
> **NOTE**: Failed
>   matches in Perl do not reset the match variables, which makes it
>   easier to write code that tests for a series of more specific cases
>   and remembers the best match.

So, if you don't want have the `$1` defined, you can enclose the matching part into a block, like:

```
use strict
use warnings;

my $u="undefined";
my $str = q{some="string" another="one"};
my($m1,$m2,$m3);

{($m1) = $str =~ m/some="(.*?)"/g;}
print 'm1=', $m1 // $u, '= $1=', $1 // $u, "=\n";

{($m2) = $str =~ m/nothere="(.*?)"/g;}
print 'm2=', $m2 // $u, '= $1=', $1 // $u, "=\n";

{($m3) = $str =~ m/another="(.*?)"/g;}
print 'm3=', $m3 // $u, '= $1=', $1 // $u, "=\n";
```

what prints

```
m1=string= $1=undefined=
m2=undefined= $1=undefined=
m3=one= $1=undefined=
```

*PS: I'm not a Perl guru, maybe others will extend/correct this answer.*